# ConcurrentModificationException when clearing a sub list

Tags: java, list

Why does the following code throw `ConcurrentModificationExcrption`, when I clear the sub List after the master List, but not if I clear the sub list and then the master List?

```
ArrayList<Integer> masterList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> subList;

// Add some values to the masterList
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    masterList.add(i * i);
}

// Extract a subList from the masterList
subList = masterList.subList(5, masterList.size() - 1);

// The below throws ConcurrentModificationException
masterList.clear();
subList.clear(); // Exception thrown in this line

// The below doesn't throw any exception
subList.clear();
masterList.clear(); // No exception thrown. Confused??
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SubList` is not an independent entity, but it is just giving a view of the original list, and internally refers to same list.  Hence, its design seem to be such that if underlying list is modified structurally (addition/removal of elements), it is not able to fulfill its contract.

As can be seen [here in the source code of SubList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.SubList.checkForComodification%28%29), the method `checkForComodification` checks whether the underlying list has been modified, and thus if the `modCount` (number of times the list has been structurally modified) value of `SubList` is not same as parent `ArrayList`, then, it throws `ConcurrentModificationException`

So, clearing parent `ArrayList` from which `SubList` was created can result in the certain operations of `SubList` to result in ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: This is very informative. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[`subList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) is a view over the `masterList`. There is just 1 underlying collection. Now masterList is kind of a `superset` of sublist. So,

- `sublist` cannot exist if `masterlist's` elements are removed //exception case
- `masterlist` can exist if `sublist's` elements are removed //OK

Comment: Is it like the subList refers to the elements of masterList and when I do masterList.clear(), the references get destroyed and subList.clear() throws an exception?

Answer (score 2):

acording to [ArrayList doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) `subList()` returns a sublist that is backed by the original ArrayList, so if the original changes so does the subList, when you execute subList.clear() the sublist itself doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 2):

From [the API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29):

> The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is *structurally modified* in any way other than via the returned list. (Structural modifications are those that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)

Undefined semantics means of course that it is allowed to throw an exception (and indeed this is probably the wisest course of action).

So you can change the size of the sublist and have those changes reflected in the main list, but the reverse isn't true.