# List ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, concurrentmodification

I have the following code

```
public void saveProjects(List<Project> proj) throws DatabaseException {
    for (Project listItems: proj) { // error here

        insertProjects(listItems);
    }
}

private void insertProjects(Project prj) throws DatabaseException {
    commitObjects(prj);
}
```

When I am executing the above, I am getting the following exception at `for (Project listItems: proj) {`

> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>       at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:449)
>       at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:420)

How can I resolve this issue with usage of next or with iterator?

Edit 1

Code snippet where I am calling saveProjects

```
projectList.add(proj);
  for (Project persist: projectList) {
       persist.setProjectId("K7890");
       persist.setName(fileName);

          myDAO.saveProjects(projectList);

     }
  projectList.clear();
```

Comment: Not sure of the reasons for the down-votes. It's a legitimate and complete question. 1+

Comment: I take that back. The typo was distracting and misleading.

Comment: What does `commitObjects(prj)` do? Does it somehow modify the `List<Project> proj`?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have included commitObjects method code snippet.

Comment: What is `callablestatement` type?

Comment: @MaximShoustin `callablestatement` is database connection type.

Comment: Can you post code where you call `saveProjects`?

Comment: That's strange, doesn't look like you modify the list somewhere. Can you try to wrap the list with `Collections.unmodifiableList(...)` before iterating over it? Are you calling something concurrently?

Comment: Why you ran twice over `projectList`. 1st loop `for (Project persist: projectList) {` and after you run again into `saveProjects`

Comment: @MaximShoustin Does that causing the exception? If so what is the best approach for this?

Comment: Some more of your stack trace showing where in the code in the code those lines are could be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From code

```
for (Project persist: projectList) { 
     persist.setProjectId("K7890");
     persist.setName(fileName);

      myDAO.saveProjects(projectList); 
 }

projectList.clear(); // <-- clear might cause to this Exception
```

*Reference*

**Why do you get a ConcurrentModificationException when using an iterator?**

The `java.util Collection` classes are fail-fast, which means that if one thread changes a collection while another thread is traversing it through with an iterator the `iterator.hasNext()` or `iterator.next()` call will throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Even the synchronized collection wrapper classes `SynchronizedMap` and `SynchronizedList` are only conditionally thread-safe, which means all individual operations are thread-safe but compound operations where flow of control depends on the results of previous operations may be subject to threading issues. (`List myList = Collections.synchronizedList (myList)` ! It may not work here)

**Solutions for multi-thread access situation**

**Solution 1**: You can convert your list to an array with `list.toArray()` and iterate on the array. This approach is not recommended if the list is large.

**Solution 2**: You can lock the entire list while iterating by wrapping your code within a synchronized block. This approach adversely affects scalability of your application if it is highly concurrent.

**Solution 3**: You can use the `ConcurrentHashMap` and `CopyOnWriteArrayList` classes,
which provide much better scalability and the iterator returned by `ConcurrentHashMap.iterator()` will not throw `ConcurrentModificationException` while preserving thread-safety.

**Solution for single-thread access situation**

Use:

```
it.remove();
```

It removes the current object via the Iterator `it` which has a reference to your underlying collection `list`.

Avoid:

```
list.remove(myObject);
```

Comment: Maxim, If I remove for loop from second, then it stops saving records.

Comment: If you commit `insertProjects(listItems);` you still get this error?

Comment: You mean directly calling `insertProjects(listItems);`?

Comment: toggle comment like //insertProjects(listItems); Maybe connection does something. Im not familar with Data access logic

Comment: When I comment `insertProjects(listItems);` then there no exceptions.

Comment: BTW, try to comment `projectList.clear();`   Take a look on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899738/java-concurrentmodificationexception-when-clearing-list-and-arraylist

Comment: Sorry, even after commenting out `insertProjects(listItems);` it does throw exception.

Comment: Yes by removing `projectList.clear()` solves the problem. I have a quetion though, do we need to clear the list after it's use?

Answer (score 1):

Looks strange, my guess is that you modify the list (`List<Project> proj`) in another thread while iterating over it?

Because you do not alter the list in any way in the code you have given us.

You can try calling the `saveProjects` method with a copy of the `proj` list.

Comment: That's a comment at best (as you have done already), not an answer.